# Python in the Global Environment, but a different version on the Virtual Environment?

Tags: python, pip, version, python-venv, pyvenv

I'm trying to solve a python installing problem that I couldn't seem to find an answer to, yet.

So I've created a virtual environment named 'venv', and in order to make the virtual environment, you should have a python installed in your computer globally before, right??

So what if the Python in the global environment is Python 3.9.0 and in the virtual environment 'venv', I want the Python version to be Python 3.8.6? How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv - here's tool for you - **Pyenv**.
It will take some time to get used to it though.

Comment: A real big thanks to you. Just to add up, I needed this because I was working on projects in a Python 3.9.0, and I was just trying to create a Discord chatbot but it only works up to Python 3.8.6 currently... so I needed to use a different version of Python in the different virtual environment. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

look into anaconda! Once you've downloaded it, you can create as many virtual environments with any python version you want.

https://www.anaconda.com/

You can use this cheat sheet on how to create/activate/deactable/manage virtual environments.

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: I'll look into this too. Thanks!